# Proof (a | b and a not divide b) -> a not divide (b+c)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove $\forall a\in \mathbb Z, \forall b\in \mathbb Z, \forall c\in \mathbb Z, (a | b \land a\nmid c) \rightarrow a\nmid(b + c)$.

Maybe a gentle nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a \mid b \iff$ 
there is a $d$
such that
$b = da$.

$a \nmid c \iff$
there are
$p$ and $q$
such that
$c = ap+q$
and
$0 < q < p$.

Therefore,
$b+c
=da+ap+q
=a(d+p)+q
$.
Since
$0 < q < p
< d+p
$,
$a \nmid (b+c)
$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response